# Travelling with US H1B visa on old cancelled indian passport

Tags: usa, indian-citizens, international-travel, h1b-visas

I renewed my Indian passport before its expiry. My old passport is marked cancelled. I have a valid H1b visa till Jan 2019 on my old cancelled passport, do I need a new H1B stamp on new passport or can I use valid visa in my old cancelled passport?

Answer (score 0):

The unexpired visa in your expired passport remains valid, and you can continue to use your existing visa to enter the US, without getting a new visa, as long as you use it with a new passport of the same type and issued by the same country as the old passport.

[FAQ from the Department of State](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/frequently-asked-questions/about-basics.html):

> My old passport has already expired. My visa to travel to the United
>   States is still valid but in my expired passport. Do I need to apply
>   for a new visa with my new passport?
>
> No. If your visa is still valid you can travel to the United States
>   with your two passports, as long as the visa is valid, not damaged,
>   and is the appropriate type of visa required for your principal
>   purpose of travel. (Example: tourist visa, when your principal purpose
>   of travel is tourism). Both passports (the valid and the expired one
>   with the visa) should be from the same country and type (Example: both
>   Uruguayan regular passports, both official passports, etc.). When you
>   arrive at the U.S. port-of-entry (POE, generally an airport or land
>   border) the Customs and Border Protection Immigration Officer will
>   check your visa in the old passport and if s/he decides to admit you
>   into the United States they will stamp your new passport with an
>   admission stamp along with the annotation "VIOPP" (visa in other
>   passport). Do not try to remove the visa from your old passport and
>   stick it into the new valid passport. If you do so, your visa will no
>   longer be valid.